# mysql stored procedure 2 IN Param from SELECT

Tags: mysql, parameters, procedure

I need to call a stored procedure that have 2 IN Param into a stored procedure and the 2 IN Param are returned from a SELECT

Ex

CREATE PROCEDURE 'xxxx'
BEGIN

....
 CALL MyProcedure ((SELECT InParam1,InParam2 FROM Table WHERE Id=1),@Out1,@Out2);
....

END

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a query to a stored procedure. Fetch the values into the local variables and use those in procedure call. Also, use local variables instead of user-defined variables as out-parameters.

The reason for using local variables is that the user-defined variables can inadvertently change when you call another procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'xxxx' 
BEGIN

declare v_in1 int;
declare v_in2 int;
declare v_out1 int;
declare v_out2 int;

  select InParam1,InParam2 into v_in1, v_in2
  FROM Table 
  WHERE Id=1;

  CALL MyProcedure (v_in1, v_in2, v_out1, v_out2); 
  ....
END
```

Comment: You cannot pass a table (many rows) as parameter in MySQL. If you need to pass multiple rows, put the data in temporary table. Both procedures can access the temp table as it is visible throughout the connection